# From main html page, How to redirect to second website(server) if the first one id down?

Tags: javascript

1. Introduction about the problem i am facing

**I have a main(index.html) page,
which, on load, checks if website1= "google.com" is online, if it is online, redirect to it,
if it does not, then it should redirect to website2= "bing.com",
but it does not.**

(the javascript code i am using, is from online sources)

What am i doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

2. This is the JavaScript code:

   ```
    <script>
    var address = "https://google.com";
    var t1 = Date.now();
    var max = 3200;
    var failed = false;
    var httpReq = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if(httpReq == null) {
        window.location.href = "https://bing.com";
    }
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var failTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                                   failed = true;
                                   httpReq.abort();
                                   }, max);
        if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {
            if (!failed && (httpReq.status == 200 || httpReq.status == 0)) {

               window.location.href = "https://google.com";
            }
            else { 
               window.location.href = "https://bing.com";
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        httpReq.open("GET", address, true);
        httpReq.send(null);
    } catch(e) {
        window.location.href = "https://bing.com";
    }
    function onSuccess(timeTotal) {
        window.location.href = "https://google.com";
    }
    function onFail() {
       window.location.href = "https://bing.com";
    }
    </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
**By not being able to solve the 'Cors' problem, i found an alternative that does the redirect (by checking if a file exists on server).**
This is the code that works for me.

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function UrlExists() {
var url = "http://example.com/favicon.jpg";
$('<img src="'+ url +'">').load(function() {
document.location.href = "https://example1.com";
    return true;
}).bind('error', function() {
document.location.href = "https://example2.com";
    return false;
});
}
    </script>
```

the original code is from:
https://iditect.com/article/how-to-check-if-a-url-file-exists-using-javascript-or-jquery.html

Answer (score -2):

I really don't know what you mean by online. This may not work because when you are using XMLHttpRequest, it has to be same origin. This is blocked due to the CORS policy.

Comment: It means that i have a main website server that i can connect to, but sometimes i have to do maintenance on it, even during the day. so by redirecting the client to the second website the user has no website interruption. To solve this i use a main login page which redirect to the first available server.

Comment: @Filo Thanks! For your problem, try checking the console (right-click, inspect, then console) and see the error that pops up. For me, it has the CORS policy error

Comment: I get this error:   Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403 [when successfully redirected to server1], and  Status code: 404 when the server is down.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, it would be better to classify it a such